# Casting a numpy array into a (different) pre-allocated array

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have an array A of dtype int32, and I want to cast it into float64.
The standard way to do this (that I know) is A.astype('float64').
But this allocates a new array for the result. If I run this command repeatedly (with different arrays of the same shape),  each time using the result and discarding it shortly after, then the overhead from these allocations can be non-negligible.
Suppose I pre-allocated an array B, with the same shape of A and of type float64. Is there a way to use the memory of B for the result of the casting, instead of allocating new memory each time?
ufuncs and numpy.dot have an 'out' argument for this, but astpye does not.

Comment: `B[...] = A`?  --

Comment: Yes of course!  Don't know why I missed this...

Answer (score 1):

As Paul Panzer commented, this can be done simply by B[...] = A.